# How do I prevent zoom over form fields when scrolling on mobile?

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile

I have an issue where I have a search box at the top of the page and on mobile if you want to scroll past it but catch one of the drop down fields my accident it zooms into it and the menu drops down. This is terrible user experience because I didn't intend to use the drop down, I just wanted to scroll past the content. Is there a best practice for forms on mobile or something that can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1, initial-scale = 1">
```